# Updating XAP withouth changing the app_id : sllauncher.exe

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-oob

I have a Silverlight application installed Out-Of-Browser on multiple computers.  Now I'd want to update the xap on those.  I dont want to manually update every computer.

I know I can do it through sllauncher.exe but the problem is that my application is changing its app_id.  I need to preserve it, is there any way to do that?

secondly, we need to specify a local file with the /install parameter.  It does not seems to work if I specify the web url to my new xap, is that normal?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized I can do it just by replacing the xap file directly in the local drive here :

"C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Silverlight\OutOfBrowser\1111111111.appName\appName.xap"

But I am not sure it doesn't mess up anything by doing it that way.  But it seems to work fine though.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use sllauncher to update your xap. All you need to do is call [CheckAndDownloadUpdateAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.checkanddownloadupdateasync%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). It will check for a new version of the xap and if one is available it will download and update it for you.

Comment: Thanks, but I like I said I dont want to manually update every computer, I'd like to do it through a batch file.

Comment: There is nothing manual about calling CheckAndDownload... from your application. Unless we have different ideas about what "manual" means

Comment: After calling CheckAndDownloadAsync, we need to manually restart the application.

Answer (score 1):

For `Silverlight OOB` applications its always better (must) to use `CheckAndDownloadUpdateAsync` (to update) which will check and download if there is a new version of the XAP. You can check this everytime the user starts the application or before closing the application, or at regular intervals. No new `app_id` is created as its updating.

You can use `sllauncher.exe` to install the XAP (it doesn't update) creating a new app_id. And the `/install:XAP file` might be a local file or a shared file. It cannot be a web url.

You can give web url at `/origin:Web Url`. This will be useful when you want to update your application.